# Symfony2 Sonata Admin Bundle as 'frontend'

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

We are running in a project which sort of looks like so:

The customers can login to a controlpanel in which they can edit information.
The information they edited will be pulled via a REST API by other software (this allready works in a previous version).

Actually the base of our application is actually the same as the SonataAdminBundle. But as far as I know I can not filter data viewed in the SonataAdminBundle by which user is logged in.

For example:

- **User1**, **User2** and **User3** are employees from **Customer1**. They only need to see the data they all added from **Customer1**
- When a new customer **Customer2** is added to the system some users are also created **User10** and **User11**. They only need to see information about **Customer2** and not the information added by **Customer1** (and vise versa)

Is this possible by using only the SonataAdminBundle? Or do we have to create our own software which is be able to to this?

I know that we have to create all different manytomany or onetomany relations, but that isn't any problem. The main question is, can I filter data by the user that is currently logged in? And when logged in as an admin or super admin no data filter must be applied.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to use only SonataAdminBundle.

First of all, the user access data by the different list view, so you need to override the createQuery method of your Admin class to display the right Customer.

(Don't forget to inject @security.context service)

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') || !$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
    {
        $user = $this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser();

        $query->
            // your custom query.
        ;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Then you need to securise all the other action (show, edit and delete) to prevent the user to access to the other Customers.

To do that i override my Controller's actions and i add my own logic before calling the parent method.

```
public function editAction($id = null)
{
    // check if the user can access to the current customer
    // if not throw new AccessDeniedException();

    return parent::editAction($id);
}
```

Perhaps there are better methods..

Comment: But something is not possible only through ACL's? I have found a bundle which probably does what I want (https://github.com/coopTilleuls/CoopTilleulsAclSonataAdminExtensionBundle)
But I think my security lacks because I only get the entities in the dashboard when the normal user has the role: ROLE_ADMIN 
When the user has the role: ROLE_USER and ROLE_[BUNDLENAME]_[ENTITY]_[GUEST/STAFF/EDITOR/ADMIN] then I think I should have access to view the entity list, but I don't get to see anything.

Comment: All of the users need to have ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN roles otherwise they will not be able to use sonata.
It's not possible to restrict the access to a specific entry with role or acl, you can only set permissions for an entire Entity.